# Changing values in a JSON data file from shell

Tags: json, bash, perl, shell, awk

I have created a JSON file which in this case contains:

```
{"ipaddr":"10.1.1.2","hostname":"host2","role":"http","status":"active"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.1.3","hostname":"host3","role":"sql","status":"active"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.1.4","hostname":"host4","role":"quad","status":"active"},
```

On other side I have a variable with values for example:

```
arr="10.1.1.2 10.1.1.3"
```

which comes from a subsequent check of the server status for example. For those values I want to change the status field to `"inactive"`. In other words to `grep` the host and change its `"status"` value.

Expected output:

```
{"ipaddr":"10.1.1.2","hostname":"host2","role":"http","status":"inactive"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.1.3","hostname":"host3","role":"sql","status":"inactive"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.1.4","hostname":"host4","role":"quad","status":"active"},
```

Comment: Consider using `jq` to parse JSON

Comment: What language is your code in? Where is your code? What problem have you encountered?

Comment: I'm using awk sed and bash to create the json file

Comment: Note that this is not valid JSON format according to http://jsonlint.com/ .. Which means that is cannot be parsed by standard modules in Perl and Python..

Comment: Actually yes this is before to added header and footer this is "thе working part"

Comment: Ok.. if you make it valid JSON, it can be done simply in Perl..

Comment: Is it meant to be an actual application or simply a quick parse/find/replace?  If the latter, then a oneliner with `jq ...` or `perl -MJSON -E '...;'` is probably simplest.  If the former, then more details about what you are trying to accomplish would be helpful for helping. Are you reading data from a web page or a JSON push service for use in some other application? Or are you building an application that should display results as well as maintain the data in your JSON data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ arr="10.1.1.2 10.1.1.3"
$ awk -v arr="$arr" -F, 'BEGIN { gsub(/\./,"\\.",arr); gsub(/ /,"|",arr) }
    $1 ~ "\"(" arr ")\"" { sub(/active/,"in&") } 1' file
{"ipaddr":"10.1.1.2","hostname":"host2","role":"http","status":"inactive"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.1.3","hostname":"host3","role":"sql","status":"inactive"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.1.4","hostname":"host4","role":"quad","status":"active"},
```

Comment: Any particular reason for the downvote for all answers?

Answer (score 2):

**Version 1**: 
Using a simple regex based transformation.  This can be done in several ways. From the initial question, the list of ipaddr is in variable in `arr`.  Example using a Bash env variable:

```
$ export var="... ..."
```

It would be a possible solution to provide this information by command line parameters.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my %inact;                    # ipaddr to inactivate
my $arr=$ENV{arr} ;           # from external var (export arr=...)
## $arr=shift;                # from command line arg

for( split(/\s+/, $arr)){ $inact{$_}=1 }

while(<>){                    # one "json" line at the time
   if(/"ipaddr":"(.*?)"/ and $inact{$1}){
       s/"active"/"inactive"/}
   print $_;
}
```

**Version 2**:

Using Json parser we can do more complex transformations; as the input is not real JSON we will process one line of "almost json" at the time:

```
use JSON;

use strict;
my ($line, %inact);
my $arr=$ENV{arr} ; 

for( split(/\s+/, $arr)){ $inact{$_}=1 }

while(<>){              # one "json" line at the time
   if(/^\{.*\},/){
      s/,\n//;
      $line = from_json( $_);
      if($inact{$line->{ipaddr}}){
         $line->{status} = "inactive" ;}
      print to_json($line), ",\n"; }
   else { print $_;}
}
```

Comment: Version 2, can be simplified if input is a complete JSON compliant file.

Comment: Could you please tell me what is wrong with my solution? Is it producing wrong results?

Comment: you didn't do anything wrong - someone seems not to have liked **any** of the answers in here. But don't worry - over time they will either get voted up.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick `perl` "wrap-around one-liner": that uses the `JSON` module and [slurps with the `-0` switch](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches):

```
perl -MJSON -n0E '$j = decode_json($_); 
   for (@{$j->{hosts}}){$_->{status}=inactive if $_->{ipaddr}=~/2|3/} ; 
   say to_json( $j->{hosts}, {pretty=>1} )' status_data.json
```

might be nicer or might violate PBP recommendations for `map`:

```
perl -MJSON -n0E '$j = decode_json($_); 
   map { $_->{status}=inactive if $_->{ipaddr}=~/2|3/ } @{ $j->{hosts} }  ;
   say to_json( $j->{hosts} )' status_data.json
```

A shell script that resets status using `jq` would also be possible. Here's a quick way to parse  and output changes to JSON using [`jq`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
cat status_data.json| jq -r '.hosts |.[] |
select(.ipaddr == "10.1.1.2"//.ipaddr == "10.1.1.3" )' |jq '.status = "inactive"'
```

**EDIT** In an earlier comment I was uncertain whether the OP was more interested in an application than a quick search and replace (something about the phrases "*On other side...*" and "*check on the server status*"). Here is a (still simple) `perl` approach in script form:

```
use v5.16; #strict, warnings, say
use JSON ;
use IO::All;

my $status_data < io 'status_data.json';
my $network = JSON->new->utf8->decode($status_data) ;
my @changed_hosts= qw/10.1.1.2 10.1.1.3/;

sub status_report {
  foreach my $host ( @{ $network->{hosts} }) {
     say "$host->{hostname} is $host->{status}";
  }
}

sub change_status {
  foreach my $host ( @{ $network->{hosts} }){
    foreach (@changed_hosts) {
      $host->{status} = "inactive" if $host->{ipaddr} eq $_ ;
    }
  }
  status_report;
}

defined $ENV{CHANGE_HAPPENED} ? change_status : status_report ;
```

The script reads the JSON file `status_data.json` (using [`IO::All`](http://www.metacpan.org/pod/IO::All) which is great fun) then decodes it with [`JSON`](http://www.metacpan.org/pod/JSON) into a hash.  It is hard to tell if this us a complete a solution because if you are "monitoring" host status then we should check the JSON data file periodically and compare it to our hash and then run the main body of the script one when changes have occurred.

To simulate changes occurring you can define/undefine `CHANGE_HAPPENED` in your environment with `export CHANGE_HAPPENED=1` (or `setenv` if in in `tcsh`) and `unset CHANGE_HAPPENED` and the script will then either update the messages and the hash or "report". For this to be complete the data in our hash should be updated to match the the data file either periodically or when an event occurs. The `status_report()` subroutine could be changed so that it builds arrays of `@inactive_hosts` and `@active_hosts` when `update_status()` told it to do so:  `if ( something_happened() ) { update_status() }`, *etc.*

Hope that helps.

**`status_data.json`**

```
{
  "hosts":[
        {"ipaddr":"10.1.1.2","hostname":"host2","role":"http","status":"active"},
        {"ipaddr":"10.1.1.3","hostname":"host3","role":"sql","status":"active"},
        {"ipaddr":"10.1.1.4","hostname":"host4","role":"quad","status":"active"}
  ]
}
```

**output:**

```
~/ % perl network_status_json.pl
host2 is active
host3 is active
host4 is active
~/ % export CHANGE_HAPPENED=1   
~/ % perl network_status_json.pl
host2 is inactive
host3 is inactive
host4 is active
```

Comment: This is a great solution! I was not aware of `IO::All`.. seems to be a great module :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/ksh

# your "array" of IP
arr="10.1.1.2 10.1.1.3"


# create and prepare temporary file for sed action
SedAction=/tmp/Action.sed

# --- for/do generating SedAction --------
echo "#sed action" > ${SedAction}

#take each IP from the arr variable one by one
for IP in ${arr}
 do
   # prepare for a psearch pattern use
   IP_RE="$( echo "${IP}" | sed 's/\./\\./g' )"

   # generate sed action in temporary file.
   # final action will be like: 
   #   s/\("ipaddr":"10\.1\.1\.2".*\)"active"}/\1"inactive"}/;t
   # escape(double) \ for in_file espace, escape(simple) " for this line interpretation
   echo "s/\\\(\"ipaddr\":\"${IP_RE}\".*\\\)\"active\"}/\\\1\"inactive\"}/;t" >> ${SedAction}
 done

# --- sed generating sed action ---------------
echo "${arr}" \
 | tr " " "\n" \
 | sed 's/\./\\./g
        s#.*#s/\\("ipaddr":"&".*\\)"active"}/\\1"inactive"}/;t#
        ' \
 > ${SedAction}


# core of the process (use -i for inline editing or "double" redirection for non GNU sed)
sed -f ${SedAction} YourFile

# clean temporary file
rm ${SedAction}
```

Self commented, tested in ksh/AIX.
2 way to generate the SedAction depending of action you want to do also (if any). You only need one to work, i prefer the second

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple indeed in Perl, using the [`JSON`](https://metacpan.org/module/JSON) module.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON qw/ from_json to_json /;

my $json = JSON->new;

my $data = from_json(do { local $/; <DATA> });

my $arr = "10.1.1.2 10.1.1.3";
my %arr = map { $_ => 1 } split ' ', $arr;

for my $item (@$data) {
  $item->{status} = 'inactive' if $arr{$item->{ipaddr}};
}

print to_json($data, { pretty => 1 }), "\n";

__DATA__
[
{"ipaddr":"10.1.1.2","hostname":"host2","role":"http","status":"active"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.1.3","hostname":"host3","role":"sql","status":"active"},
{"ipaddr":"10.1.1.4","hostname":"host4","role":"quad","status":"active"}
]
```

**output**

```
[
   {
      "role" : "http",
      "hostname" : "host2",
      "status" : "inactive",
      "ipaddr" : "10.1.1.2"
   },
   {
      "hostname" : "host3",
      "role" : "sql",
      "ipaddr" : "10.1.1.3",
      "status" : "inactive"
   },
   {
      "ipaddr" : "10.1.1.4",
      "status" : "active",
      "hostname" : "host4",
      "role" : "quad"
   }
]
```